# loading css in asynchronously imported javascript using webpack with MiniCssExtractPlugin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-5, preact

i'm working on a webapp that loads it's different pages asynchronously via dynamic imports e.g.:

```
import {Component, h} from "preact";
import AsyncRoute from "preact-async-route";

import {Layout} from "components/layout";
import {PageLoading} from "components/page-loading";

export class Page extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Layout>
                <AsyncRoute
                    key="doorstation"
                    path={"/doorstation"}
                    getComponent={this.getSamplePage}
                    loading={() => <PageLoading />}
                />
            </Layout>
        );
    }

    async getSamplePage(){
        const { init, Page } = await import("modules/sample");

        init();
        return Page;
    }
}
```

and in the actual imported file i do

```
// modules/sample/page/index.tsx
import {Component, h} from "preact";
import styles from "./styles.css";

export class Page extends Component {... components logic}

// modules/sample/index.tsx
export const init = () => // some initialization logic
export { Page } from "./Page"
```

Each of those pages has their own css that gets imported on their respective file. What i'm stuck now with is that it puts the resulting css in it's own chunk but when the browser build tries to import said css it just fails with an error like:

```
GET http://<my-ip>/341.()=%3E%225028a51a47a787d4cc85%22.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
Error: Loading CSS chunk 341 failed.
(/341.()=>"5028a51a47a787d4cc85".css)
    at o.<computed>.o.<computed>.<computed>.e.push.o.<computed>.d.onerror
```

on inspection of the import on the console the href of resulting stylesheet tag is actually set to:

```
link.href = "http://<my-ip>/341.()=%3E%225028a51a47a787d4cc85%22.css"
```

what i expected was that webpack would resolve those paths on my dynamically imported modules but apparently this isn't the case.

for now my config looks like this:

```
module: {
   rules: [
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
                {
                    loader: args.mode === "production" ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader : "style-loader",
                },
                {
                    loader: "css-loader",
                    options: {
                        sourceMap: args.mode !== "production",
                        importLoaders: 1,
                        modules: {
                            localIdentName:
                                args.mode === "production"
                                    ? "c-[hash:base64:8]"
                                    : "[name]-[local]-[hash:base64:4]",
                        },
                    },
                },
                {
                    loader: "postcss-loader",
                },
   ]
},
plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: "[name].[hash:8].css",
        chunkFilename: "[name].[hash:8].css",
    }),
]
```

by just using the style-loader everything works just fine but this won't give me actual css chunks. I'm not entirely sure where or what to change so webpack will require the actual css chunk files instead of resolving the path with that... what looks like an function expression. I was already looking up the issue but so far it didn't really solve my issue since it usually revolved around undefined values or something.

Did i miss something in this config? is someone able to help?
Thank you in advance.